# Spring JavaMailSender - Change Password?

Tags: spring, passwords, jakarta-mail

I have a JavaMailSender bean implemented in Spring. My beans looks as so:

```
<bean id="mailSender"
        class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com"></property>
        <property name="port" value="587"></property>
        <property name="username" value=""></property>
        <property name="password" value=""></property>
        <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.ssl.trust">smtp.gmail.com</prop>
        </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

It all works fine, so there's no issue. Someone brought up an interesting point. What if someone logs into Gmail and changes the password? Is there a way of editing the password from a web interface, or of setting the value from a database?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is load the username and properties from a properties file and initialize the bean with properties from that file? So when the password is changed you change the properties file and not the bean definition.

Here is the sample code :

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>
                classpath:mail.properties
            </value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Your `mail.properties` file

```
username=abc
password=abc
```

Your bean definition

```
<bean id="mailSender"
        class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com"></property>
        <property name="port" value="587"></property>
        <property name="username" value="${username}"></property>
        <property name="password" value="${password}"></property>
        <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.ssl.trust">smtp.gmail.com</prop>
        </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

If you are looking at storing the password in a database and editing from a web application, then you will have to build that web application and then make the `JavaMailSenderImpl` use the username/password values fetched from the database at runtime.